# How do transfer Google Calendar 'all day' events from one month to the other?

Tags: google-calendar

I put my tasks on my calendar as 'all-day' events (there is Google Tasks for Calendar but I don't want to use it). However, since August ended with a Saturday, there is not a single day of September displayed on the month view of August, so I can't drag-and-drop my events from August to September. I don't want to click and go to the edit view of every single August event/task and change the date to September.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your settings and change **Week starts on:** to **Monday**. Drag all your events, then change **Week starts on:** back to **Sunday** (if that is what you prefer).

You can also use the mini-calendar in the left sidebar: click and hold on the first day of August, then drag down into September. All the days you select will appear in the main calendar view.

Comment: The first is really a bad and unnecessary workaround. The second is helpful, but changed in the latest version: you cannot select more than 4 weeks (so you have to start dragging at the end of August) and then you cannot extend the selection more than 1 or sometimes 2 weeks into the next month.

Comment: Can we split up this answer, so we can downvote the first paragraph and upvote the second? :)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to custom weeks view (can be configured to 2, 3 or 4 weeks in the settings), then click the first week you want to see in the little calendar on the left.

If you want 4 weeks without changing the settings, you could use drag and drop in the little calendar (like the other answer suggests) and when this doesn't allow you the 4 weeks you like, edit the URL and replace /2/ by /4/ :)
(and if you think you're smart - more than 4 doesn't work anymore, unfortunately)